# Is there an implementation of (hybrid) bottom-up merge sort where merged array size is not equal to power of 2?

Tags: arrays, mergesort

The "pure" bottom-up merge sort can merge only two sorted arrays, and the only array which is "surely" sorted has a size of 1. That's why the algorithm creates sorted arrays of size 2,4,8...

But since the small arrays can be sorted more efficiently by simple (asymptotically slower) algorithms, the hybrid implementation is used very often. My question is: are there implementations where the "simple array's" size is not a power of 2? For example, 10? Where and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a hybrid bottom up merge sort / insertion sort will choose a group size between 16 and 128 elements so that the merge sort does an even number of passes, so that the data ends up back in the original array (since these merge sorts typically change the direction of merge between original and working array on each merge pass). There is nothing special about a power of 2 for the insertion sort, so any reasonable size for insertion sort groups can be used.

I haven't investigated algorithms for choosing an "ideal" group size. A crude approach is to determine the number of passes for a "pure" merge sort which is ceil(log2(n)), and if the number of passes is odd, use 32 or 128 for the group size, and if even, use 64 for the group size. Consider the case where *n* = 8000000. The number of passes for a pure merge sort is 23, so choose 32 or 128 for group size, reducing the number of passes to 18. For an attempt at an improved choice (turns out it is not an improvement), if the number of passes would be odd, use group count of 17 to 32 or 65 to 128, and if the number of passes is even, use group count of 33 to 64. Consider cases where *n* = 1 + some power of 2. For *n* = 1+2^22 = 4194305, the number of passes is 23, and using group size of 32 reduces this to 18 passes, while 128 reduces it to 16 passes. Then calculate ceil(n/(2^18)) = 17 or ceil(n/(2^16)) = 65.

---

I've since tested using 17, 32, or 65 for *n* = 1+2^22 = 4194305, with C++ code (Visual Studio 2015, Win 7 Pro 64 bit), and it made virtually no difference, the variation was within the variation I get from doing repeated runs with the same code (less than 1.5% variation).

Comment: "so that the merge sort does an even number of passes"
So if the insertion sort works on subarrays of size K, then the first merge occurs on length/K arrays. Probably a lazy thinker, but how much should length/K be?

Comment: I think the group size should be ceil(length/2**2k) which is unlikely to be a power of 2. find `k` that makes this group size in the range 16 to 64 and apply insertion sort on the groups before shifting them into the bottom up merge sort array. This ensures that the merge phases are performed on subarrays of similar sizes, especially the last ones.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes - Using a Java test program, with 1+2^22 = 4194305 elements, there's almost no difference in time between 17, 32, or 65. 65 was maybe 3% faster. I need to retest in C.

Comment: You should also consider when the insertion sort will be more efficient in terms of actual complexity.

Comment: On a 31M input (random sequence of numbers 1-31111111), the difference is 1-2 secs, so I guess it hardly matters and is more of a measurement thing (I use one CPU with RealTime priority).

Comment: @Ferazhu - I updated my answer, using C++ code, and for `n` =  1+2^22 = 4194305, there was virtually no difference (it was less than the variation from run to run).

Comment: Good, I was running through all Insert-Sort sizes from 1 to 200. At the higher sizes, the whole algorithm obviously starts being less efficient.